# Is there anything similar to Browserlink for ASP.NET in WPF?

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

When I'm debugging an ASP.NET / ASP.NET MVC project, after installing [web essentials](http://vswebessentials.com/),  I can go on the browser, click on the part of the HTML which I want to investigate and with a simple click I can see the source code (Aspx) that has generated that visual part (html).

It's called [browser link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/06/28/browser-link-feature-in-visual-studio-preview-2013.aspx)

Is it possible to achieve something similar in WPF?

Comment: Do you mean a debugger?

Comment: @PeterRitchie: no, a tool similar to snoop that shows you the source code which generated the visual part of the WPF application which you are hovering with the mouse. It's incredible that it's available from microsoft for ASP.NET and not for WPF...

Comment: I've voted this tool on the Microsoft website. https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6445042-easy-visual-debugger-for-wpf-to-find-the-source-co

Comment: I've debugged the code generated by the WPF code generator--it's on the hard drive.  So, it appears you need to be more clear with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF Inspector https://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/
or Snoop http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/
may give you some information about the structure of the WPF Visual Tree.  It isn't exactly the source code that generated the UI in the same way Browser Link works, but it might get you closer to what you need.

Comment: Thanks, if you like you can vote on the microsoft website the proposal of doing a similar instrument for WPF: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/6445042-easy-visual-debugger-for-wpf-to-find-the-source-co